# insert to sp list is not working with spservices

Tags: spservices

```
<script src="../../../_layouts/Gridwebpart/jquery-1.6.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../../_layouts/Gridwebpart/jquery.SPServices-0.7.2BETA1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<SharePoint:FormDigest ID="FormDigest1"  runat="server" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //GetKeywordList();
    });
    function AddNewSPListItem() {
        alert($('#<%=txtName.ClientID %>').val());
        var Title = $('#<%=txtName.ClientID %>').val();
        var Description = $('#<%=txtDescription.ClientID %>').val();
        alert(Title);
        $().SPServices({
            operation: "AutocompleteKeywordList",
            async: false,
            webURL: window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host,
            listName: "GridList",
            updates: "<Batch OnError='Continue' PreCalc='TRUE'>" +
            //Cmd = 'New' is a command to add new record in the list.
                       "<Method ID='1' Cmd='New'>" +
                       "<Field Name='TopNumber'>1</Field>" +
                       "<Field Name='Title'>" + Title + "</Field>" +
                       "<Field Name='Description'>" + Description + "</Field>" +
                       "</Method>" +
                       "</Batch>",
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                alert("success");
            }
        });      //End SPSErvices
    }
    </script>
```

**ERROR**

> have alert(Title); its undefined will val() work in sharepoint

Comment: whats the error ?

Comment: i have  alert(Title);
 its undefined will val() work in sharepoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function AddNewSPListItem() {
alert($('#<%=txtName.ClientID %>').val());
var Title = $('#<%=txtName.ClientID %>').val();
var Description = $('#<%=txtDescription.ClientID %>').val();
alert(Title);
$().SPServices({
operation: "UpdateListItems",
async: false,
webURL: window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host,
listName: "GridList",
updates: "<Batch OnError='Continue' PreCalc='TRUE'>" +
//Cmd = 'New' is a command to add new record in the list.
"<Method ID='1' Cmd='New'>" +
"<Field Name='Title'>" + Title + "</Field>" +
"<Field Name='Description'>" + Description + "</Field>" +
"</Method>" +
"</Batch>",
completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
alert("success");
}
}); //End SPSErvices
}
```

EXPLAINATION:
There was no fieldname called   "Field Name='TopNumber'>1 Field" +
So the whole operation was failing.

Also instead of  operation: "AutocompleteKeywordList",
it should be operation: "UpdateListItems",

Comment: can you explain what was the problem with code in question plss

Comment: updated the answer